# Transformation of kurtotic distribution with mean approximately 0

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation, kurtosis

I have a dataset of population growth rates (pgr). Most of the observations are relatively small (positive and negative) but there are also somewhat more extreme values (also  positive and negative). The distribution is quite symmetric. To normalize the distribution I thought to take the square root of the absolute value and making the originally negative ones negative again.

`delta$pgr.sqrt <- ifelse(delta$pgr >=0, sqrt(abs(delta$pgr)), -sqrt(abs(delta$pgr) ))`

This makes the distribution better and after regression (mixed model) the residuals seem fine.
I tried to find information about this type of transformation but could not find anything which makes me wonder if it is reasonable to do it this way? Would this be a rare situation, a stupid solution or am I overlooking a better solution?

Comment: I haven't heard of such a transformation but I might just be "uneducated" on this.In general dividing a sample $S$ by the standard deviation of it allows you to "set the $Var(S)$ = 1". Maybe trying a Box-Cox transformation (or a power transformation in general) would be a more structured approach for handling excess kurtosis/skewness. In the R-library "car", you may find the function bcPower() to perform standard power transformations of this sort.

Comment: There may be better approaches. How are these rates measured? Are they, for instance, obtained as ratios (or log ratios) of two populations at two times? If so, are they the same times for each record? If not, then how are the rates determined?  Note, too, that the characteristics of these rates by themselves are almost irrelevant for regression: what matters is the distribution of the regression *residuals.* What does that distribution look like?

Comment: @ user11852: as far as I know a Box-Cox transformation requires positive values. Of course, one can add the absolute value of the minimum to the original values before the Box-Cox transformation. But is that better?

Comment: @ whuber: the rates are log ratios of abundances in successive years: pgr = log(N_t+1) - log(N_t). I don't see what other rate I could use to circumvent the problem. Also I don't understand what you mean by "are they the same times for each record". I agree that the residuals should be checked (I did). The "extreme" residuals tend to reflect the extreme original observations.

Comment: @EOF: changing your intercept should not change your model in a non-trivial way. Nevertheless, you need to make sure you "reverse transform" your model's findings so their interpretation is meaningful. As you said, defining your new sample to be equal to $S$ + abs(min($S$)) should ensure you have non-negative values (maybe add a bit of salt there so something like $S$ + abs(min($S$)) + 10^(-7))...

Comment: @user11852: When I do S + abs(min(S)) + something small and then do some power transformation this will treat the large values different than the ones that are small (I tried it using bcPower; not extensively though). The variance of the original negative tail is reduced more than the variance of the original right tail. This does not occur with my proposed transformation. I am grateful for your suggestion but still not convinced that it is any better while I am still also doubtful about my original "solution". Regards.

Comment: @EOF: I don't think you really "mind that"; there is no concept of "reducing the variance more to the one side rather than the other". You are working with transformed data; end-of-story. You can moment-adjust the transformed data by finding the (α,λ) pair, where α is the added intercept and λ the power parameter such that the new sample $S <- bcPower(S + α, λ)$ is "as normal as possible" (eg. Kurtosis = 3 & Skewness = 0). As whuber said, the regression residuals are the "important" bit, maybe you don't need to transform your data to start with.

Comment: You convinced me to do Box-Cox. I am fully aware of your and whubers advice to check residuals. Thank you for your advice.